# Mosquitto bridge with TSL/SSL Support: OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, mosquitto, broker

I'm trying to set up a bridge between two mosquitto brokers. And I'm having trouble configuring the config files and generating the required certificates.

Broker A: Acts as a bridge, on a local computer

Broker B: on AWS server, regular SSL connection, just collecting data from Broker A.

The steps I have taken:

1. sudo openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
2. sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
   2.1. In this step, for the "Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)" I provide the IP address of Broker A.
3. sudo openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
4. sudo openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
   4.1 Here I provide the IP address of my AWS server.
5. sudo openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 3650

I share the ca.crt with Broker A.

Broker A: config file:

```
# listen to the local data I have setup (works fine)
listener 1883

connection target-broker
address 3.208.62.218:8884
bridge_cafile E:\SSL\ca.crt
topic MSUFridge/#
```

Broker B (AWS) config file:

```
listener 8884

allow_anonymous false

certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
```

But this fails and the AWS says:

```
New connection from 75.152.250.126:52995 on port 8884.
Sending CONNACK to MSU.target-broker (0, 5)
Client MSU.target-broker disconnected, not authorised.
```

P.S I have generated all the certificates on AWS. But I also tried generating the "server" files on the local machine and faced the same issue.

I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to do with SSL/TLS, but because you haven't configured any user authentication in the AWS broker.

```
listener 8884

allow_anonymous false

certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
```

`allow_anonymous false` means that the other broker must supply a username & password and the AWS broker must have a list of authorised users.

You should look at the mosquitto man page for how to create a password file and how to include it in the config.

You can also configure the username to use for the bridge on the local broker.